# Help me clarify this really unclear diagram?

Tags: mosfet, driver, h-bridge, diagram

---

[image]

**5.2 Reduce control IC exposure**

- 2a. Connect VS and COM as shown in Figure 6.

http://www.irf.com/technical-info/appnotes/an-978.pdf

(H-bridge application notes)

---

Do they want me to connect the VS pin to the COM pin, or is that some sort of typo?

EDIT: Please note there is literally no VS pin in this diagram. VSS doesn't mean anything when using the 8-DIP package, and COM does not look directly connected; so what the hell am I doing when it says to connect them, just taking a wire and soldering it to both VS and COM? Or do I run it through a decoupling/low-pass filter, a resistor, what exactly do I do.

---

Comment: Yes, they want you to connect those pins. Other figures also show those two pins connected. This one is about *how* they should be connected

Comment: That stops it from being a 'floating' high-side, though. And also, do you just stick a jumper wire between it or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way they are asking you to connect the VSS and COM pins is to avoid load ground currents infiltrating the logic ground connection.

COM is a floating output and naturally should directly connect to H bridge 0V (shown as a large rounded rectangle). VSS is fed from the logic 0V directly. The logic 0V is, in turn, fed from the rectifier return point. This prevents H bridge currents flowing thru the more sensitive logic 0V and corrupting the logic ground with noise.

Comment: VSS isn't present in the 8-DIP. Only Vs/COM. Same deal?

Comment: No Vs is something else - please provide a link to a picture of the device in its 8 pin format - need pin names as well. I couldn't see this version in the document you linked.

Comment: That app note says connect Vs and COM to kill undershoot. Here is my 8-DIP; http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/ir2183.pdf

Comment: You cannot connect Vs to COM. If you had a device with a VSS pin, it can connect to COM but better to use the diagram in your question. For 8 pin devices it appears there is no VSS pin.

Comment: So when it says VS in section 5.2, it really means VSS then, right? Because it really does not say VSS, and test circuit 5B has COM and Vs connected.

Comment: When it says "connect Vs and COM as per figure 6" it means "VSS" and not "Vs".

Comment: How'd you figure that out? To me it looks like even in their example circuits, there is a separate VSS and Vs pin. And Vs is connected to COM through a 100uH inductor.

Comment: Figure 6 doesn't show Vs and yes, Vss and VS are different pins. Figure 5b is a test circuit and it doesn't mean you operate the device with an inductor across Vs and COM.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Cool!